# Is it bad practice to pass in a new instance of an object that might go unused into a method?

Tags: php, laravel

I'm using laravel 5.8 and I'm in a situation where I need to repeatedly check if a variable exists in session to return and if not, use a new instance of a class and return that.

Depending on the variable I'm looking for in session, it'll also need a different type of class. So what I've done is simply pass in a new instance of what ever object I need and use that if needed.

```php
private function getModel($request, $var_name, $new_model)
{
    if (empty($request->session()->get($var_name))) {
        return $new_model;
    }

    return $request->session()->get($var_name);
}

$applicant = $this->getModel($request, 'applicant', new Applicant);
$spouse = $this->getModel($request, 'spouse', new Spouse);
```

The code works, but my concern lies in whether or not this is bad practice. Will instantiating these classes without using them waste memory?

Answer (score 0):

Why are you overthinking for that? If it can affect your system if you remove it, then don't think too much about it. You can learn everyday and can find solution in a easiest way. Don't overthinking it will exhaust you and affect your productivity. As long as is it readable and not super slow then its okay.